# Got blocked by Google Finance

Tags: google-chrome, web-scraping, google-finance

I was trying to write come code for stock market predictions and everything was working fine until it suddenly stopped working and threw an error:

```
----> 1 get_price_data({'q': 'GOOG', 'i': 86400, 'x': 'NASDAQ', 'p': '1Y'})

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googlefinance/client.py in get_price_data(query)
     12         for price in lines:
     13                 cols = price.split(",")
---> 14                 if cols[0][0] == 'a':
     15                         basetime = int(cols[0][1:])
     16                         index.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(basetime))

IndexError: string index out of range
```

I went to http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:GOOG
and it said there " We're sorry... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now." ............

So i googled it and on the help page it said "

If you see a message that says "We're sorry, but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.":

Open this reCAPTCHA page.

If you see a normal CAPTCHA (letters or numbers) your computer and network are safe. The site you came from could have a configuration problem. Try to let them know about it.

If you still see the "We're sorry, but your computer..." message, then there may be something wrong. See the tips at our unusual traffic help page.

"

but clicking on "this reCAPTCHA" sends me to as error page "Not Found Error 404"

What do I do?

I tried asking on the Google forum, and immediately got a bunch of hacker responses asking to install remote desktop control :\ ...

Comment: You could try using published APIs (if they exist) instead of attempting to violate their terms of use with automated queries.   That is a serious answer, the server response is telling you you're doing something that you're not supposed to do.

Comment: @DaveS, it is using their API. https://pypi.org/project/googlefinance/ "Python module to get stock data from Google Finance API"